# FocusChangedEventHandler in java

Tags: java, com, ui-automation, jna

I am trying to monitor the UI element focus change using `IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler`.

Tried something from what I could understand but it seems to give me an `IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance`.

Could someone please help/guide me with it?

Thanks in advance.

Attached is my code.

**In main.java**

```
automation.AddFocusChangedEventHandler(null, new FocusChangedEventHandler());
```

**FocusChangedEventHandler.java**

```
public class FocusChangedEventHandler implements IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler {

    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public <T extends IUnknown> T queryInterface(Class<? extends IUnknown> comInterface) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int addRef() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int release() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void handleFocusChangedEvent(IUIAutomationElement sender) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(Unknown Source)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.ComObject.prepareArgs(ComObject.java:213)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.ComObject.invokeVoidCom(ComObject.java:379)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.ComObject.invoke(ComObject.java:637)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.AddFocusChangedEventHandler(Unknown Source)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.test.othermethod(test.java:47)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.test.main(test.java:12)
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens added. Sorry for not including that before.